# Upgrade/Update Windows 8 customer preview to normal version

Tags: windows, windows-8-preview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will it be possible to upgrade from Windows 8 Previews to the RTM version?](https://superuser.com/questions/439898/will-it-be-possible-to-upgrade-from-windows-8-previews-to-the-rtm-version)

Is it possible to update/upgrade the windows 8 customer preview in the future to the normal version?
I plan to install windows 8 in the future, but right now I want to start with preview. Can I upgrade? Or the need to raise again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft, this will not be possible.  You can't upgrade to the RTM version.

Comment: On a personal note, unless you're incredibly savvy, DON'T INSTALL IT YET.  Wait for it to be fully ready.

Comment: Installing it is more fun.  Plus, as a base install, it is faster than Win7.

Comment: I recommend grabbing the Professional version Like I have. Boy it feels good to be a member of DreamSpark.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how it is the preview, even if it were possible, it would not be recommended.  I doubt it will be possible, as they are still working heavily on the final build.  In a similar vein, why the urge to upgrade so quickly to an unproven system.

Comment: I agree with the advice about no upgrade to RTM.  However, one thing puzzles me there was an upgrade from the Developer Preview to the Consumer preview, thus it should be technically possible, if not desirable to upgrade.  Also these are the most stable 'betas' that I have ever seen, hence it being tempting to upgrade to the RTM - but it's not possible!

Answer (score 0):

**Upgrade from Preview to RTM works!** When you get following error message you can just do below simple change.

> You can't upgrade this prerelease version of Windows. Go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=142337 to see how to install Windows and keep your files and settings.

Just change one file in the installation directory. I'm using a USB Stick to install Windows 8 and changed the file **/sources/cversion.ini** to

```
[HostBuild]
MinClient=7100.0
MinServer=7100.0
```

Before it was twice the value 8508.0.

Then the upgrade from a Windows 8 Preview to RTM worked without any problems. Even after some days of usage no problem discovered. But be aware - this is officially not possible, so you may have issues that aren't known so far...