# Upgrade to Windows 8 from Release Preview?

Tags: upgrade, windows-8-preview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will it be possible to upgrade from Windows 8 RC to the RTM version?](https://superuser.com/questions/439898/will-it-be-possible-to-upgrade-from-windows-8-rc-to-the-rtm-version)

I've seen the upgrade offer from Microsoft that allows upgrading to Windows 8 from Windows XP, Vista and 7.

If I already upgraded my Win7 to Win8 release preview, do I have to downgrade first to upgrade to final windows 8 ?

Can I upgrade to final windows 8, if I did a clean install of Win8 release preview ?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

More to the point.

I'm not worried about settings... I'm wondering whether, if I do a clean install of RP, (for free, obviously), will I get Win 8 Pro for $40 ? Or do I have to do an upgrade from Windows 7 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It hasn't been confirmed, but accorind to Paul Thurrott and Mary Jo Foley on Windows Weekly  (http://twit.tv/ww) you will be able to upgrade from RP to RTM, but you won't keep your settings.

Comment: Thanks @Rev. I'm not worried about settings... I'm wondering whether, if I do a clean install of RP, (for free, obviously), will I get Win 8 Pro for $40 ? Or do I have to do an upgrade from Windows 7 ?

Comment: I believe as long as you have a computer that can run the program (meaning any Windows installation) you should be able to use the $40 method. It may even work for pirated or unactivated copies of Windows, but obviously that's not legal. We won't know for sure until Windows 8 comes out for sure.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that it will be possible for $40. See [here](http://hothardware.com/News/Windows-8-Pro-Release-Preview-Users-Eligible-for-40-Upgrade-Promotion/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

**Upgrade from Preview to RTM works** even without loosing settings. When you get following error message while installing Windows 8 you can just do below simple change.

> You can't upgrade this prerelease version of Windows. Go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=142337 to see how to install Windows and keep your files and settings.

Just change one file in the installation directory. I'm using a USB Stick to install Windows 8 and changed the file **/sources/cversion.ini** to

```
[HostBuild]
MinClient=7100.0
MinServer=7100.0
```

Before it was twice the value 8508.0.

Then the upgrade from a Windows 8 Preview to RTM worked without any problems. Even after some days of usage no problem discovered. But be aware - this is officially not possible, so you may have issues that aren't known so far...

Comment: When I upgrade this way, given that I clean installed Win 8 RP (not upgraded from Win 7), does that mean I can upgrade with the $40 upgrade deal ? or do I still have to buy the full Win 8 key ?

Comment: I don't know - I hope so, because you have a valid Windows 7 licence, so it should be possible, otherwise you just call Microsoft and tell that you've tested the Windows8 Preview prior to Upgrade. I'm sure they will give you a licence for $40.