# How do you upgrade from Windows 8 Release Preview to Windows 8 RTM?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will it be possible to upgrade from Windows 8 RC to the RTM version?](https://superuser.com/questions/439898/will-it-be-possible-to-upgrade-from-windows-8-rc-to-the-rtm-version)

I've read numerous articles on Superuser but none of them are precise. They're all like 'maybe you can, maybe you can't". Can anyone please tell the steps on upgrading RP to RTM?