# How can I upgrade to "official" Windows8?

Tags: upgrade, windows-8-preview, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will it be possible to upgrade from Windows 8 RC to the RTM version?](https://superuser.com/questions/439898/will-it-be-possible-to-upgrade-from-windows-8-rc-to-the-rtm-version)

I have Windows 8 RP on my laptop; I think I've read that it won't be possible to upgrade from RP to the RTM version of the OS. If that's true, how do I proceed to get the final version installed on/after 10/26? I don't want to lose all my apps/data that are already installed...

Comment: @DaveM - While this is indeed a duplicate the accepted answer to that question is 100% wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also note that the final release of Windows 8 will not support upgrading from any prior Windows 8 "Preview" release, though the migrate option will still be supported.
>
> Microsoft does not recommend upgrading from a beta, and may actively prevent it.
>   Windows RTM should always be clean installed which means preferred applications and utilities have to be clean installed too.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/will-i-be-able-to-upgrade-windows-8-release/12a00692-1758-4082-a0ec-31e0f666d980

> While it is possible to transfer your personal files from Windows 8 Consumer Preview to Windows 8 Release Preview using Windows Easy Transfer, we do not recommend using Windows Easy Transfer to also move your settings.   If you do chose to use Windows Easy Transfer to transfer your personal files, it is very important that you follow these steps precisely so that you do NOT also transfer any Windows settings or apps settings.
>   It should also be noted that Windows Easy Transfer will not move your apps – they will need to be reinstalled after installing Windows 8 Release Preview.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/how-to-use-windows-easy-transfer-to-migrate-your/4ab6ee9f-9c19-4f91-b826-83b1248a6a20

Answer (score 0):

```
I have Windows 8 RP on my laptop; I think I've read that it won't be possible to upgrade from RP to the RTM version of the OS. If that's true, how do I proceed to get the final version installed on/after 10/26? I don't want to lose all my apps/data that are already installed...
```

As long as you upgraded a previous retail version of Windows, you will be able to upgrade from one of the preview releases of Windows 8, of course only your user files will be transfered.

It is the same migration support that exists migrating from Windows XP to Windows 8.

**Some of the information in the accepted answer is outdated.  The second quote isn't even talking about upgrading to the RTM build of Windows 8.**