# Can I upgrade from Windows 8 Release Preview to Pro version

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will it be possible to upgrade from Windows 8 RC to the RTM version?](https://superuser.com/questions/439898/will-it-be-possible-to-upgrade-from-windows-8-rc-to-the-rtm-version)

I have laptop with Windows 7 that came on it. I have a key on the back of my laptop. Now I replaced the hard drive with the SSD drive and installed Windows 8 RP on it from the scratch. Will I be able to purchase upgrade key for Pro version upon release date 26 Oct?

Also can I upgrade simply from my Windows 8 RP to Pro version or do I need to reinstall it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't qualify for the $14.99 [Upgrade Offer](http://www.windowsupgradeoffer.com) unless you have bought/buy a Windows 7 PC between June 2, 2012 and January 31, 2013.

You can always purchase the $39.99 upgrade though (max 5 upgrades per person; price valid till January 31, 2013 at least), or the $69.99 upgrade with the DVD. The RP *can* be upgraded and qualifies for the offer, even if it was a clean install.

As per [this article](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/print/9228798/FAQ_Microsoft_offers_cheapest_ever_Windows_upgrade) a clean install of the RTM version is possible using the offer, but you will initially need to use the Upgrade Assistant to *qualify* the PC, which probably means you'll need a genuine key for Windows 7 at hand.