# Windows 8 Release Preview to Windows 8 Pro on New Dell Laptop

Tags: windows-8-preview, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will it be possible to upgrade from Windows 8 Release Preview to the RTM version?](https://superuser.com/questions/439898/will-it-be-possible-to-upgrade-from-windows-8-release-preview-to-the-rtm-version)

I bought Dell Laptop with Windows 7 last month, and opted to get windows 8 at a discount when it was released
I have a Windows 8 Release Preview disk and I'm eager to install and to use Windows 8 on my laptop.

Can i update to the RTM version of windows from release preview with a update key?

Comment: please ask *one* question at a time. Your second question has been answered already. http://superuser.com/questions/439898/will-it-be-possible-to-upgrade-from-windows-8-release-preview-to-the-rtm-version

Comment: @nhinkle, Thanks... My question is slightly different from that. Any way thanks for close without clear understanding.