# Is it possible to buy Windows 8 online as a digital download?

Tags: operating-systems, download, windows-8

Is it possible to buy windows 8 online as a digital download? (the full install **non-upgrade** version)

Similar to the way windows 8 upgrade can be bought as a digital download from [windows.microsoft.com](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/buy?ocid=GA8_O_WOL_DIS_ShopHP_FPP_Light) but for the full version.

Comment: Yes, of course I searched. A lot. And no results. That is why I asked here...

Comment: @r.tanner.f No worries - I am honestly really surprised that MS does not have it linked there for a full ISO, so the assumption makes sense.

Comment: I was able to upgrade to Windows 8 using the upgrade assistant from the release preview. You're only allowed to keep your personal files using this upgrade path though. The official upgrade offer [terms](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-8/terms-conditions) does not include this path and I did upgrade to release preview from Windows 7, so I am not entirely sure if this would work. However, if you don't mind spend the time downloading and installing the preview, you can try "upgrading" this way.

Comment: The link op posted let me purchase and 'upgrade' a Windows 8 Preview edition that was *not* itself an upgrade. So I'm guessing as long as you can run the tool at that link on any version of Windows it should let you?

Comment: @Mufasa: From what I know it has to be a licensed XP, Windows Vista or Windows 7 to be able to upgrade. I also read on many sites that you can upgrade from Windows 8 Release Preview but only if you have a license of one of the above. I run the tool on Windows 8 RP and it worked.

Comment: @RăzvanPanda I saw somewhere that the universal upgrade might be a promotion during the release of Win8, so I'm not sure if it will last. But for what it's worth, my copy of Win8 Preview was a clean, original install, without entering any previous license key — just the free one they e-mailed me; and it let me upgrade to Win8 RTM for the $40 upgrade price.

Comment: @Mufasa: It might be possible but I don't think it is allowed. Read this question, it is interesting: http://superuser.com/q/439898/90320

Comment: @RăzvanPanda: Technically, I meant "migrated" Windows; true the _in-place_ upgrade wasn't available. My point was that I paid the Upgrade _price_.

Comment: @Mufasa: What I meant to say is that it doesn't seem to be allowed to upgrade from Release Preview to RTM without having bought a **previous license** of XP, Vista or 7. I am not doubting that it is possible, just that it is legal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"As previously announced, the lineup does not include a full package product (FPP) SKU for retail purchase. Instead, consumers will be allowed to buy the OEM product, install it on a new PC or in a virtual machine, and take advantage of the Personal Use Rights section of the OEM license. That represents a significant savings for consumers, who can pay $140 for a full license for Windows 8 Pro rather than $275 for the full retail package."

http://www.zdnet.com/prices-and-packaging-for-windows-8-go-public-7000005685/

[Full version OEM here](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16832416550&nm_mc=AFC-C8Junction&cm_mmc=AFC-C8Junction-) but not a digital download, I am willing to bet MS will offer the Full version OEM for download at some point, time will tell. Their big push right now is get as many people to "upgrade" as they can by offering the discounted price.

Comment: The OP is asking for an online download version though. The retail version box version can be bought on Amazon for $68.88.

Comment: "I am willing to bet MS will offer the Full version OEM for download at some point, time will tell." Best anyone can do since no one knows at this point in the game if MS will offer digital downloads of OEM Full version to the general public.

Comment: @billc.cn please post the link to Amazon, MS said they will not sell a full "retail" version anymore only Full version OEM.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-3UR-00001-Windows-8-Pro/dp/B008H3SW4I/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1351287341&sr=8-1&keywords=windows+8

Comment: You're probably right all info listed in the [the Amazon Product page](http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-3UR-00001-Windows-8-Pro/dp/B008H3SW4I/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1351287341&sr=8-1&keywords=windows+8) seems to say it's the upgrade version in a box, but it says nothing like that in the title (sneaky amazon!). However, its page does list upgrading from the release preview as a valid upgrade path, so one can legally install the release preview and "upgrade" from that.

Comment: @Moab: I'll accept your solution as correct until we get an update. But I couldn't find Windows 7 digital edition either, so, probably there won't be any digital edition.

Comment: @RăzvanPanda - The answer is no, there isn't a digital copy of the OEM license sold by Microsoft ( or their partners ) currently.  Of course the physical media is exactly the same.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can get directly with no upgrade option and a Direct ISO image, unless you are in Microsoft Student Academic Alliance. Simply Dream Spark.

Microsoft offers for students to research and provide solutions if they find any dissatisfaction in the Software free of Cost.

Comment: could you provide a link please?

Comment: I can provide you a link. But unless you are Microsoft or a student from a renowned university where Microsoft offers such. You cannot download. But as for for information check this link. If find useful for your question. Please raise flag. https://www.dreamspark.com/Student/Default.aspx

Comment: I thought you meant I could also get windows 8 without dreamspark. Thanks anyway! :)