# Can i buy one windows 8 dvd and install on 2 laptops of mine?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does a full, retail license of Windows 8 exist? (Not OEM, not upgrade)](https://superuser.com/questions/494782/does-a-full-retail-license-of-windows-8-exist-not-oem-not-upgrade)

I will buy windows 8 soon, I have 2 laptops and want to know if it will allow me to install the same windows on both machines or i should buy an extra licence?

Comment: You can use the same disk, but you only be able to legally activate a single system.

Comment: Only if you are wearing an eyepatch and have a hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer, **legally:no**.

When you have two laptops, you expect both of them to be able to validate their licenses with Microsoft. That won't be possible. Only one of them will be activated at one time.

**[Personal Use License](http://personaluselicense.windows.com/en-US/default.aspx)**

> Can I transfer the software to another computer or user? You may
>   transfer the software to another computer that belongs to you. You may
>   also transfer the software (together with the license) to a computer
>   owned by someone else if a) you are the first licensed user of the
>   software and b) the new user agrees to the terms of this agreement. To
>   make that transfer, you must transfer the original media, the
>   certificate of authenticity, the product key and the proof of purchase
>   directly to that other person, **without retaining any copies of the
>   software**.

```
                    ^              ^
```

Answer (score -1):

Technically yes,

- Install on first laptop.
- **Wipe from first laptop**.
- Install on second laptop.

So yes, you can install it twice.

Comment: You *know* that's not what he was looking to do! :) (I didn't downvote you BTW.)

Comment: I know. But I can not believe the OP was as stupid as his question. Nobody is that dense. So I answered in kind. :)

Comment: Meh, I remember seeing a few more in this vein in the last few days... Apparently *some* people are! (Possibly they're thinking of going legit for the first time?)

Comment: "Nobody is that dense" oh really? You should hang out in some area's where I live.