# Buying Windows 8 OEM

Tags: windows-8, license, oem

A local internet store sells Windows 8 OEM for around 90 Euros.

Can someone tell me what OEM Windows means?

Can I install it on my own PC (built by myself)? Any differences with an off the shelf Windows 8?

Comment: Just a thought: 90 Euros sounds pretty expensive, especially for OEM. Have you looked at Microsoft's site?

Comment: I shall look more :P

Comment: possible duplicate...http://superuser.com/questions/494782/does-a-full-retail-license-of-windows-8-exist-not-oem-not-upgrade/495100#495100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 8 changed the license in OEM "System Builder" software, anyone can buy it and use it. The ["Personal Use" license clause](http://personaluselicense.windows.com/en-US/default.aspx) allows you to transfer it to other hardware also.

So look for "system builder" OEM, it replaces the old Retail Full Package Product we have been use to for XP-W7

Answer (score 1):

OEM (original equipment manufacturer) software/hardware are made to be sold to manufacturers, not consumers. Are they usually identical, minus fancy boxes and manuals? Yep!

In other words, you can buy and install this. Especially with Windows 8 which includes a "System Builder" OEM licence.

Also, that seems pretty expensive! [It's cheaper on Microsoft's website.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/buy)

Comment: ME DUMB...so I reccon you mean I can not install it on my self-built PC? So why the heck they selling it online?

Comment: No, as I say, aside from "fancy boxes and manuals" they are IDENTICAL.

Comment: You *can* install it on your self-built PC.  You're the manufacturer, aren't you?  The only difference is the terms of the license.

Answer (score 1):

OEM come without a box and are beneficial for companies as they can get tax/vat rebate on this in some cases making it more profitable for them. OEM's can be installed onto new PC's for the convience of the customer..

Retail boxes come in a nice box that you would buy and never opened by anybody. You always should get a sealed ans squeaky clean CD.

Both version are the same but the the licenses vary for the person selling it on.