# Windows 8 isn't available for download

Tags: windows-8, setup

Just downloaded the `Windows 8 Upgrade Assistant` and only got the following message:

"Windows 8 isn't available for download", "Sorry, Windows 8 isn't available for online purchase in the country/region you're in."

I which region is then a download available?

[image]

Comment: Do you use a proxy of some sort?

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. I'm in Denmark. I posted about it on Microsoft Community: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/windows-8-isnt-available-for-download/50b43e85-afea-4951-b29e-7ca66164693d.

Comment: Why did you forget to say you were doing it in windows 8? and why did you run windows 8 upgrade in windows 8? It is already windows 8?

Comment: @ppumkin, I did this thing to use the Windows 7 upgrade code for $14.99. You can't enter it anywhere else AFAIK, and I already had Windows 8 RTM setup, just not activated.

Comment: Check this here to Upgrade from Windows 8 Preview to Full Version: http://superuser.com/a/483380/161601

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see you are running the wizard in Windows 8. Try running the wizard in compatibility mode (say Windows XP SP3).

Comment: Correct! :-) This is really the error message when you run the Windows 8 Installer already on a Windows 8! Nice error message though!

Comment: Maybe by changing the "version" information in Windows 8 it can be possible: http://superuser.com/a/483380/161601

Comment: It's not possible [for a reason](http://superuser.com/a/493328/9666), you might experience a fail later if you'd ignore that.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a list of the countries and regions included in the terms and conditions of the promotion: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/terms-conditions

Comment: My Country is listed... but doesn't work

Comment: It may be due to an improperly reported geolocation, or the update may have delayed availability for your region. Unfortunately, the error is non-specific, so, it's difficult to say what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

While you might be able to *trick* it into doing the upgrade, you really shouldn't...

Previews are not meant to be used by end customers (you can, but stability isn't guaranteed) and thus will not provide upgrade paths like those for end customers. It doesn't even make sense to introduce an upgrade path from a *preview* version to the full version. If they were to introduce an upgrade path for this, they would have to deal with a lot of *fixes* to corruption that was introduced by using the previews, which is one of the main reasons the upgrade path isn't even considered.

If you care for your data and not run into corruption or a buggy OS some time later, install it clean.

Comment: Anyway my experience: A Windows need to be installed from time to time (maybe I'm still paranoid from the Windows before Win 7). I'll do that as soon as it starts bugging or getting slower and slower ;-)

Comment: I run my OSes years on without problems, it's a matter of with which mentality you approach it. I agree it's a necessity prior to Windows XP and perhaps even still with Windows XP, but nowadays it's become pointless unless something craps out. Upgrading from a preview is enough to provoke such thing...

Answer (score 1):

Check your system Time and Time zone. Check your IP address Geo Location. I think both of these didn't match.

Comment: Just checked here: http://www.ip2location.com/ and everything is ok. Correct location / Time / Timezone...