# Windows 8 Upgrade without Upgrade Assistant?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 8 isn’t available for download](https://superuser.com/questions/493138/windows-8-isnt-available-for-download)

I have a purchased copy of Windows 7 and want to take advantage of the $40 upgrade to Windows 8.  (Actually, I am currently running Windows 8 RTM and would like to upgrade this to a full version, but I think this is irrelevant to my question).

I downloaded the upgrade assistant and ran it on Windows 8.  It said some of my apps were incompatible (funny since they're running fine on Windows 8) etc, and I opted to continue.  It then told me that it is not available in my country (I'm currently in Mexico).

My question is, how can I get around this?  Can I download the ISO somewhere, and then purchase an upgrade key without going through the Upgrade Assistant?  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why did you run the assistant in Windows 8? Which version is it - the Release preview? Also take a look at [Windows 8 isn't available for download](http://superuser.com/questions/493138/windows-8-isnt-available-for-download)

Comment: It's RTM. I just want to download the ISO and pay the $40 or whatever it is to get a legit license. Maybe it'll work if i run it from my previous win7 VM?  or maybe its a regional thing?

Comment: The offer is valid in [Mexico](http://www.windowsupgradeoffer.com/en-US/Home/Faq#FAQPage_Category6Question1Literal.Text). Try again, maybe the problem was temporary and caused due to heavy load on the servers.

Answer (score 0):

No, the upgrade assistant is the only option, outside of buying the physical media (as of now) you will just have to wait till it is released in your region.

Comment: That's rediculous. And i'm sure there's a way around this - are microsoft really shutting off all of mexico from the upgrade assistance option? I doubt it...

Comment: Microsoft does what it wants.... That is how big corporations work in America.. The government tries to make laws and tell them how to behave, ultimately it is up to the Company to abide by the laws (they have plenty of money to pay fines). Love it or hate it, but that is how Corporate America works. However any of this shouldn't matter as it should be available in your region now.